# How to make 1. space between text boxes created from javascript 2. align them with another text box from jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Please help me to solve two issues:
1. Make space between each additional textbox that is created from javascript 
2. Align (from left at some position)the textboxes that are created from javascript with another textbox created from jsp

so basically, there is a textbox from JSP on the JSP page, when user clicks on Add button, the Javascript code adds additional textbox each time. I want the existing box from jsp and the addtional textboxes from javascript align at certain position from left and space between each textbox from javascript.

Thanks in advance

The Javascript and jsp code are below:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
         var table = document.getElementById(tableID);


        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

        var element1 = document.createElement("input");

        element1.type = "checkbox";

        cell1.appendChild(element1); 
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);


        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        var element2 = document.createElement("input");

        element2.name = "choiceEntry";
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.size = "100";


        cell3.appendChild(element2);


    }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
 </SCRIPT>
<html>


<form method="post" action="poll_save.jsp">

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="0">

    <TR> 

       <!-- <TD> 1 </TD>-->
        <TD><INPUT type="text" class="bigText" value=" 
<%=choice.getChoiceEntry()%>"  size = "100" name="choiceEntry"/> </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
    </TR>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: Do you want them to stack horizontally on the same row?

Comment: Thanks sigmaSoldier for your post. I would like to have different rows vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want, but if you only want a vertical spacing and a left margin between inputs you'll be fine with this:

```css
form[action="poll_save.jsp"] table input {
  /* Your left offset here */
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

And for the code, add new inputs can be done in many ways, one might be:

```js
const addOne = document.querySelector('#add-one');
const table = document.querySelector('#dataTable tbody');

let i = 0;
addOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
    table.innerHTML += `
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input name="input-${i++}" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  `;
});
```

Perhaps you might want something more flexible? I mean like making them align to the center of their container? If that's the case, please provide a sketch of what you want to make it clearer.

Also my personal recommendation is that you move your style needs to css, do not leave them in the tags (Things such as `<table width="..." ...>`) and to not use IDs, or only IDs, I recommend you to add classes, specially for styling.

Here you have a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sigmasoldier/kw8x3b42/2/

Note that there the *JSP* input is not written in JSP, but you can image that it has the JSP syntax.